# How to Hide/show Sections made by elementor using class or id after purchase?

Tags: php, woocommerce

I want to hide section and show other after customer purchase state completed !

i have woocommerce php code do that on add to cart button
can we chang it to make it do what i want ?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'bbloomer_hide_add_cart_if_already_purchased', 9999, 2 );
 
function bbloomer_hide_add_cart_if_already_purchased( $is_purchasable, $product ) {
   if ( wc_customer_bought_product( '', get_current_user_id(), $product->get_id() ) ) {
      $is_purchasable = false;
   }
   return $is_purchasable;
}
```